# Apache Superset How can I pass a filter value from a filter box to a SQL query Group By clause

Tags: apache-superset

I have a superset dashboard wherein i have a filter box containing the name of various dimensions such as area, district, country and so on. I want to generate a run time query to compute the value of a specific metric group by each of these dimensions. The user will select a value of the name of each dimension from the filter box and the dash should run the query for example:

```
SELECT 
     SUM(REVENUE),
     {{dim}}
FROM mytable 
GROUP BY {{dim}}
```

WHERE dim can be 'area' or 'district' or 'country'
How can I achieve this using Jinja templating ? Looking for any examples that would be helpfull ?

Comment: The [filter_values](https://superset.apache.org/docs/installation/sql-templating#available-macros) macro may provide the functionality you require.

Comment: Yes I tried the filter_values and it replaces the column name in the select statement but then it also adds it in the where clause causing the query to get no results.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use different column names in Filter and your chart.
An example of the same is here:
https://github.com/apache/superset/discussions/15272